# Make some posts disappear?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed

We are starting to get quite a few posts that are not spam but are so far off they are cluttering up the site and possibly being hit in searches and attracting  more similar posts. Is there a way to have them really gone not just closed? A few hours after I made this post we now do have spam.

Answer (score 1):

For true spam posts, they are closed and removed immediately, but deleting [closed] posts is ***traditionally*** performed by vote of the community.

Wide-spread cleanups haven't happened (yet) because, in the life cycle of a *typical* site, [pro tem moderators](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) are appointed before ongoing cleanups begin in earnest (it's part of the community taking ownership of the site). But Patents SE was created  outside our normal process. To date, I've been shoring up the role of community *self*-moderation to keep things going while we add staff to make a proper go of this.

Long story short, I've seen the increase in out-of-place posts too, and I need to do a cleanup. The clutter and [broken windows](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/246/67) are becoming too frequent and problematic to wait for the normal processes.